# nested for loops stored in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a nested for loop and I want the results be stored in a nested list as well.
my code is as following:

```
n_row = 5
n_col = 2
result = []
for r in range(n_row):  
    for c in range(n_col):
        a = r*2
        b = c+1
        d = a-b
        result.append(d)
```

The result is as following:

```
[-1, -2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
```

however, I want each row to be in a separate list and the result to look like the following:

```
[[-1, -2], [1, 0], [3, 2], [5, 4], [7, 6]]
```

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create each row as you iterate over them:

```py
n_row = 5
n_col = 2
result = []
for r in range(n_row):
    row = []
    result.append(row)
    for c in range(n_col):
        a = r*2
        b = c+1
        d = a-b
        row.append(d)

print(result)
```

I create each `row` and `append()` to it, but I append the row to the `result` list rather than each calculated element.

Output as requested.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite the loop as answer by @quamrana,
but if you are looking for a hacky quick solution, append the following to your code:

```
result2 = [[result[n_col*k+i] for i in range(n_col)] for k in range(int(len(result)/2))]
```

What this does is it loops over your original "result", n_col at a time, and constructs a new array.

For easier understanding, note that for n_col=2, you could equivalently use:

```
result2 = [[result[2*k], result[2*k+1]] for k in range(int(len(result)/2))]
```

Relevant resource: [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  You just need to append rows to your result and add the values to each row rather than adding them to the top level list:

```
n_row = 5
n_col = 2
result = []
for r in range(n_row):  
    result.append([])         # <-- add a row
    for c in range(n_col):
        a = r*2
        b = c+1
        d = a-b
        result[-1].append(d)  # <-- add to last row
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your result by:

```
n_row = 5
n_col = 2

k=[(r*2) - (c+1) for r in range(n_row) for c in range(n_col)]
print(k)
[-1, -2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]

#Desired output

print([k[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(k),2)])
[[-1, -2], [1, 0], [3, 2], [5, 4], [7, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
n_row = 5
n_col = 2
result = []
for r in range(n_row):  
    row = []
    for c in range(n_col):
        a = r*2
        b = c+1
        d = a-b
        
        row.append(d)
    result.append(row)
        
print(result)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?